# Java based solution for file archive

Tags: java, file, archive

I need to create some kind of file archive - with control of MD5, meta-information of files,etc. Remove from archive by date. Do exist some open source solutions, frameworks for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSR-170 and JSR-283 define such functionality.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_repository_API_for_Java

Apache Jackrabbit - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Jackrabbit - is the reference open source implementation.